# How to quickly jump to the folder containing the email?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016, microsoft-outlook-365

My workflow is as follows:

1. Get new e-mail for a certain order which may have been years in the past
2. Search for messages in conversation to find older emails
3. I now want to move the new email to that folder
4. For that reason I want to open the folder quickly in the Outlook folder tree

How to do the last item "quickly jump to the folder containing the email I'm just watching, or even better: which I'm right clicking"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use this macro to jump to the folder of search result directly: [Get the Message Folder](http://vboffice.net/en/developers/get-the-message-folder/).

It works for me very well, you could try it:).

Comment: Good enough, thank you so much!